# PublishSubject with backpressure in RxJava 2.x

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I am currently choosing between RxJava 1.x or 2.x for my current project.

I basically need a `PublishSubject` with a backpressure strategy `onBackpressureLatest()`.

I want to choose RxJava 2.x, but i can't quite get my head around on how to apply a backpressure strategy to a `PublishSubject`, as it inherits from `Observable` and not from `Flowable`.

---

Could you please tell me how to create a `PublishSubject` with a `onBackpressureLatest()` backpressure strategy in RxJava 2.x ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In 2.x the backpressure was moved to the base type Flowable and its hot partners PublishProcessor, ReplayProcessor etc.

```
PublishProcessor<Integer> pp = PublishProcessor.create();
Flowable<Integer> out = pp.onBackpressureLatest();
```

Comment: @akarnokd How to call the onNext() of subscriber of Flowable in this case? I tried to do pp.onNext(1) but it's not calling the flowable's subscribers onNext()

Comment: @SandipSoni Please open a question where you detail exactly what you have and what you tried, with source code.

Answer (score 5):

I used at some point something like this:

```
Subject<Object> emitterSubject = PublishSubject.<Object>create().toSerialized();

emitterSubject.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
```