# RxJava subscribe Subject to Flowable

Tags: rx-java2

This might seem like an obvious question but I cannot seem to find the answer. I would like to subscribe a `Subject` to a `Flowable` but this method doesn't seem to be implemented:

```
Flowable<Long> flowable = Flowable.just(1L, 2L, 3L);
Subject<Long> subject = PublishSubject.create();
subject.subscribe(System.out::println);
flowable.subscribe(subject); // Method cannot be resolved
```

However for Observable it is implemented:

```
Observable<Long> observable = Observable.just(1L, 2L, 3L);
Subject<Long> subject = PublishSubject.create();
subject.subscribe(System.out::println);
observable.subscribe(subject); // Works
```

What am I missing? Is there an obvious reason as to why it isn't implemented? Are `Flowable` and `Subject` incompatible for some reason? Or is there another method to reach my goal?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42185853/publishsubject-with-backpressure-in-rxjava-2-x)

Answer (score 2):

A `Subject` is an `Observer`, so you can can subscribe it to an `Observable` but not to a `Flowable`.

Instead of using a `PublishSubject`, you can use a `PublishProcessor` ([Api docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/processors/PublishProcessor.html)).